# Rally Pyral API Key Proxy Issue

Tags: rally, pyral

I am trying to replace my old username/password Rally authentication with Rally API Keys.

```
server, user, password, workspace, proj = rallySettings(options)
rally = Rally(server, user, password)
```

to

```
rally = Rally(apikey='SECRET_KEY')
```

When I made the change, I started getting errors like: ('Cannot connect to proxy.', gaierror(-5, 'No address associated with hostname')).

If I switch back to the old user/password route, it works just fine.

Here's how I am setting the proxy:

```
proxy = "http://internal.proxy.com:port"
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = proxy
os.environ['https_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = proxy
```

I'm using pyral 1.1.1 and requests 2.3.0 on a redhat server.  Any ideas why switching from Username/Password to APIKeys would cause a proxy connection issue?

Answer (score 1):

ApiKey replaces username/password, but it does not replace host.

This line:

```
rally = Rally(apikey='SECRET_KEY')
```

is missing host(server)

See an example [here](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForPython/blob/master/examples/periscope.py).

```
if apikey:
        rally = Rally(server, apikey=apikey, workspace=workspace, project=project)
    else:
        rally = Rally(server, user=username, password=password, workspace=workspace, project=project)
```

Comment: Good point!  I added the line, so it now looks like: rally = Rally('rally1.rallydev.com',apikey='KEY'), but I am still getting the same error....